# How can i change a component according to url but not change the page? React

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, components

For example i have a page **/profile** on there, the user isshowed his profile picture. When the respected user clicks on it, it changes to **/profile/avatar**. But, i dont want to change the page but show a component which otherwise will not be shown in **/profile**. Think of it as when you click on another's avatar in twitter, it changes to **/@elonmusk/pfp** a modal shows the image but it doesnt unmount the previous page

How can i implement that?

Comment: You can simply direct the route to the same component and check if the `pfp` param exists to render kind of a "modal". The profile component shouldn't get unmounted if the route changing is aiming to the same component :)

Comment: What version of `react-router` do you have installed? You can check by running `npm list react-router react-router-dom` in the terminal from your project's directory. What have you tried? Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).